# Using QMetaObject from DLL causes memory access error

Tags: visual-c++, dll, qt5, qobject, moc

I am having trouble using the QMetaObject (more specifically the staticMetaObject property) from within a DLL. I have narrowed down to the following small example:

TestLib.h

```
#pragma once

#include <QObject>

class TestClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    static QString testMethod() { return "TestString"; }
};
```

TestLib.cpp

```
#include "TestLib.h"

QString s1 = TestClass::testMethod();

// The line in question. If this line is commented out, the code works!
QString s2 = TestClass::staticMetaObject.className();
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QLibrary>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QLibrary lib("testlib.dll");
    qDebug() << lib.load();
}
```

If the line above is commented out, the `lib.load()` returns `true`, otherwise `false`.
If run using a debugger, a memory access violation at address 0x0 is reported in the line in question.

Is this a bug in Qt? Can QMetaObjects not be used in DLLs or am I doing something wrong?